# MVC5 dependency injection issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have created an application using MVC5 with the onion architecture approach. The solution contains 3 projects (core, infrastructure, and UI). The UI contains both Web API controllers and MVC controllers. The issue I’m running into is dependency injection. I have installed Unity.MVC5 & Unity.WebApi.  My `UnityConfig.cs` under `App_Start` Looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IPricingService, PricingService>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

My global.asax looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

    }
```

To test out my controller, I defined my home controller like this:

```
private readonly IPricingService _pricingService;

    public HomeController(IPricingService PricingService)
    {
        this._pricingService = PricingService;
    }
```

When running home page I get 
***No parameterless constructor defined for this object.***

Now, moving to another test scenario, I created a web api controller and looks like this:

```
private readonly IPricingService _pricingService;

    public TestApiController(IPricingService PricingService)
    {
        this._pricingService = PricingService;
    }
```

Testing the web api generates this error:

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TextApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Not sure what I'm missing. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to inject the `Unity.WebApi.DependencyResolver` into the WebApi configuration **not** in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

You also need to implement a child container in the `BeginScope` method [as shown in this MSDN article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, going to try that shortly.but what about the regular controller that generates the same error? Does this resolve both issues?

Comment: doesn't work. Can you provide an example that works with MVC5 + Web API? Thanks

Comment: it works with MVC5 + Web API. But there is no need to install Unity.WebApi.DependencyResolver if Unity.MVC5 is installed. Thanks @nightowl888